# WSO2 IoT 3.0.0 and 3.1.0 Device Location Not Showing

Tags: wso2

After enrolling a device and going to the Device Location tab I get the following errors and it shows a blank grey box where the map should be. I did not had this with EMM 2.2.0.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
>   https://172.16.21.73:9443/devicemgt/api/invoker/execute/
>       combined.js:5094 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
>           at loadLeafletMap (combined.js:5094)
>           at HTMLLIElement. (combined.js:5120)
>           at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
>           at HTMLLIElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)